# How to auto delete the expires data in the database?

Tags: django

If I store a row data in the database table(`instance`), and the table has a field names `expire_time`. if the time over the `expire_time`, I want to delete the row data.

So, if I want to do that, I can every time query the table, traverse every row data, if expires, then delete.

But if I don't query I can not realize the requirement.

So, if there is a method to do that?

I use python django, the database is mariadb.

Comment: Have you considered the [Django's cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/)? Maybe it is what you want, maybe not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) to do this for you. Save this in `myapp/management/commands/delete_expired.py` for example:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import timezone
from myapp.models import MyModel


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Deletes expired rows'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        now = timezone.now()
        MyModel.objects.filter(expire_time__lt=now).delete()
```

Then either call that command from a cron task or a queue. To do it on the command line you can call:

`python manage.py delete_expired`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by:

> I can not realize the requirement.

But I think you might want consider:

- [custom manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) command, and cron this command with your venv python source
- add [django-cron](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron) to routinely check for expired data and delete it
- try [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) as another solution to cron but it could be too complecated for your case
- add [event to MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/events/) and schedule it periodical

The drawback of custom manage.py cmd and event is if you migrate server you should remember to add new cron job/event to clean db periodicaly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a database-level approach to do that (maybe you want to add the `mariadb` tag if you are looking for a database-specific solution).

At the application level, an approach comes to mind. You may use Celery and, whenever you store a row data, schedule a task to delete it. The celery task should check that expire_time is effectively invalid (can that field be modified or updated?).

You can also (in addition or as an alternative) have a Celery beat job that periodically gets the element with smaller expire_time. If it should be removed, removed and call itself again. Otherwise, wait for next beat.